# invalid method decl/illegal start of type/identifier expected/( expected java

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
    int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(1500);
    displayHighScorePosition("Joey", highScorePosition);
    
    public static void displayHighScorePosition(String playerName, int highScorePosition) {
        System.out.println(playerName + " managed to get into position " + highScorePosition + "on the high scores!");
    }

    public static void int calculateHighScorePosition(int playerScore) {
        if (playerScore > 1000) {
            return 1;
        } else if (playerScore > 500 && playerScore < 1000) {
            return 2;
        } else if (playerScore > 100 && playerScore < 500) {
            return 3;
        } else {
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm getting errors :

Error:(7, 9) java: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(7, 34) java: illegal start of type
Error:(16, 23) java:  expected
Error:(16, 24) java: '(' expected

Comment: The `}` ending `main` should come after the calls to `calculateHighScorePosition` and `displayHighScorePosition`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Why don't you provide that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did some basic mistakes in your code, first of all, there were two lines of your code placed in nowhere. Another one error, you wrote 2 returns in only one method. The class shold be like it:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(1500);
        displayHighScorePosition("Joey", highScorePosition);
    }
    


    public static void displayHighScorePosition(String playerName, int highScorePosition) {
        System.out.println(playerName + " managed to get into position " + highScorePosition + "on the high scores!");
    }

    public static int calculateHighScorePosition(int playerScore) {
        if (playerScore > 1000) {
            return 1;
        } else if (playerScore > 500 && playerScore < 1000) {
            return 2;
        } else if (playerScore > 100 && playerScore < 500) {
            return 3;
        } else {
            return 4;
        }
    }
    
}
```

I strong recommend you study more basics of Java.

Comment: I am currently and was stumped. Thought I would ask.

Answer (score 1):

You misplaced the curly brace of your `main`-method.

```
int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(1500);
displayHighScorePosition("Joey", highScorePosition);
```

Should also be placed inside the method.